# Jest not awaiting timeout before test completes

Tags: async-await, jestjs

I have a test that awaits an async function, then awaits a timeout, then awaits another async function.

```
it('runs a snipe successfully', async () => {
      const exitCode = await john.chat.sendMoneyInChat(channel.topicName, channel.name, "0.01", botUsername);
      console.log('timeout?')
      await timeout(3000);
      console.log('timeout!');
      console.log('running bal check')
      let values;
      const nbl = await croupier.checkWalletBalance(process.env.CROUPIER_RINGO_USERNAME);
      expect(nbl).toEqual(123);
})
```

Based on my console.log output, the `afterAll` teardown process begins right after the `timeout?` log statement.  In other words, I don't see "`timeout!`" in the console log – I see the console.log statements within the afterAll teardown.

What gives?

EDIT:

Thanks to @Metalmi's help, I've fixed one bug.  Now my code is:

```
  it('runs a snipe successfully', async () => {
        jest.useFakeTimers()
        const exitCode = await john.chat.sendMoneyInChat(channel.topicName, channel.name, "0.01", botUsername);
        console.log('timeout?')
        jest.advanceTimersByTime(20000)
        console.log('timeout.');
        console.log('running bal check')
        let values;
        const nbl = await croupier.checkWalletBalance(process.env.CROUPIER_RINGO_USERNAME);
        expect(nbl).toEqual(123);        
  });
```

Here's the checkWalletBalance function:

```
  public checkWalletBalance(username: string): Promise<any> {
      let balance: number = 0;
      const self = this;
      return new Promise(async (resolve) => {
        try {
          const acct = await self.bot1.wallet.lookup(username);
          console.log("acct", acct);
          const balances = await self.bot2.wallet.balances(acct.accountId);
          console.log("balances", balances);
          balances.forEach((acctDetail) => {
            console.log(acctDetail.balance[0].amount);
            balance += parseFloat(acctDetail.balance[0].amount);
          });
          resolve(balance);
        } catch (e) {
          console.log(e);
          throw e;
        }

      });
    }
```

I am guessing there is some problem of having async functions inside the Promise?

The Jest teardown starts before console.log("acct", acct) happens within `checkWalletBalance`, so something's still wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use/test standard timer functions, you need to instruct jest to use fake timers: [jest.useFakeTimers()](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestusefaketimers). Then you need to manually advance time: [jest.advanceTimersByTime(msToRun)](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestadvancetimersbytimemstorun)

EDIT:

Issue is that you declared Promise as async, and not the `checkWalletBalance()` itself. Changing that should fix it.

Also, to be sure about assertion being checked, you can call [expect.assertions(1)](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#expectassertionsnumber) at the beginning of test, so jest knows that test must have at least one assertion and won't finish before it's checked.

Comment: What if I need to wait for an external API call to handle its business?  It there a solution for that other than mocking the call?

Comment: In that case, your test needs to be async (as yours is) and you just need to use await, to wait for the API call to finish.

Comment: That is helpful, but it seems like I have one more bug!  I call await foo(), and it's skipping through to the end and running teardown.  Editing main question with details.

Comment: Have edited main question with details.  I think it's something funky with awaiting a Promise that itself calls multiple async functions?

Comment: @ZackBurt, just to let you know that I've updated my answer, in case you missed it.